# Azure Media Services and existing Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Can Azure Media Services re-use an existing Storage Account, for example one we use for Table storage ? Or is this Storage Account dedicated only for AMS ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an existing storage account as long as it's redundancy type is Locally Redundant, Geo-Redundant, or Read-only Access Geo-Redundant.

[image]

Comment: Additionally - recommend always using General Purpose v2 account types of course.  
And keep in mind that we will generate containers in that storage account for encoding jobs, Assets, etc...  You should never mess with those containers directly. You should always use the Assets API to add and remove them.

Comment: @johndeu...May I ask what benefit do we get out of General Purpose v2 accounts in context of Media Service? I have found them to be more expensive that v1 accounts.

Comment: They are the newer account types that can support useful features like storage tiers on assets. V1 storage accounts are considered legacy.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview

Comment: @johndeu, thanks! I am aware of the benefits of v2 accounts over v1 account. My question was usage of these features in context of Media Service. It's been a while that I used Media Service, hence the question :). I mean I could simply take an asset container in a v1 account and copy it another container in v2 account and change it's access tier. I would not be paying for high transaction costs for v2 accounts (and they are significantly higher than v1) to stream the content.